# Excel VBA constant arrays to vba code array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on excel VBA school assignment and I have an issue and can't seem to find answer online.
 I have database table that holds information, in certain location I have constant array of ={false, true, false} and I need it to convert it to VBA array TF(1 to 3)
 TF(1) should have value of false
 TF(2) should have value of true
 TF(3) should have value of false
so far my code looks like this:

```
Sub trying()
Dim TF(1 To 3) As String
Set targetWorksheet = Worksheets("duomBazeSheet")
Worksheets("duomBazeSheet").Activate

With targetWorksheet
    TF(1) = .Cells(2, 8).Value
    MsgBox (TF(1))

End With
End Sub
```

"duomBazeSheet" is a sheet that has all data in it and target location is (2, 8)

any ideas?

edit: here's link how sheet looks : array is highlighted https://imgur.com/a/lII3c

Comment: Looks like it should work. Where's the problem?

Comment: it gets only 1st value, i want to print 2nd value (true)

Comment: what were you expecting? You are assigning a value to the array from the worksheet

Comment: you need to loop the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a feature called Evaluate one can do this

```
Dim tf
tf = Application.Evaluate("{True,False,True}")
```

Given the formula text in H2 try this ...

```
Sub Test()


    Dim tf
    tf = Application.Evaluate(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).Formula)

    Dim i
    For i = LBound(tf) To UBound(tf)
        MsgBox tf(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: it's nice, sorry to post same link again, I have array highlighted :
https://imgur.com/a/lII3c
that's my issue :( it's constant array that needs to be transfered to vba
it's not in different lines

Comment: or just `tf = Evaluate([duomBazeSheet!H2].Formula)`

Comment: it gives me this :( "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

The following code declares and populates a one-dimensional array with the values false, true, false. The `For` Loop will display each element at the end. It is unclear where you want to place these values.

```vb
Sub trying()
    Dim TF As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet

    Set targetWorksheet = Worksheets("duomBazeSheet")

    With targetWorksheet
        TF = Split(.Cells(2, 8).Value, Chr$(10)) 'Chr$(10) is a carriage return
    End With

    For i = LBound(TF) To UBound(TF)
        MsgBox TF(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why set the array values as `String`s and not `Boolean`s?

Comment: @Tom, agreed. I don't make the requirements, I just follow along.

Comment: I know, but i need to get false true false, from the constant array (={false, true, false}) from the sheet

here's the sheet https://imgur.com/a/lII3c

Comment: Or use the `" "` delimiter if the array does not have commas.

Comment: hmm, it only gets false value

Comment: Updated. This works for me. I noticed in the photo that the values seem to have carriage returns between them. I used `chr$(10)` as the delimiter of `Split`. Works like a charm.